# Preview uploaded file in React Native Expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am trying to preview the file (which can be pdf or img or doc) after uploaded by user.
I tried this but it preview file with specific url and i want it preview uploaded file only. any one have idea?

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <View><StatusBar style="dark" /></View>
        <Text>{Constants.manifest.sdkVersion}</Text>
     
        <PDFReader
          source={{
            uri: 'https://www.solarwinds.com/-/media/solarwinds/appoptics/product-screenshots/ao-infrastructure-monitoring-dashboard.ashx',
          }}
          webviewProps={{
            startInLoadingState: true,
          }}
        />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the library you're using in your question.

Normally using `source={require("./path/to/your/file")}` should work, but it depend on the library you're using support it or not.

Comment: am using PDFReader, but in source how can i make it depends on what the user upload? not just uri

Comment: Can you tell me where is your PDFReader come from? There are a hundred of libraries for reading pdf file like `react-native-pdf` or `react-native-pdf-viewer`. Depend on how the library support they will have options for you to open the one that your user upload.

Comment: By the way, if you're using `react-native-document-picker` to select pdf file. When you pick up a file from storage, it will return you an object with a key name `uri`. Then you can use it like this `source={{uri: picked.uri}}`. Maybe it's worth to try.

Comment: I have tried document picker but nothing happen after selecting  the document, i will try what you recommended

Comment: I see, here is from documentation of `rn-pdf-reader-js`. `uri: can be local or served on the web (ie. start with `https://` or `file://`)`. You can try using `source={{uri: "file://path/to/your/file"}}`. Also you can use `source={{base64: "data:application/pdf;base64," + your_pdf_base64_encoded}}`.

Comment: Can you please explain "file://path/to/your/file"? What do you mean?

Comment: It's the directory path to where your file store at, usually as above comment, document pick will return you an object with key `uri`. That `uri` is path to your file.